# Shiny Dashboard Auto Triggering

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, shiny, rstudio, shinydashboard

I had created one live Shiny dashboard. I know how to publish it in shinyapps.io.

Q1: I'm fetching data from json api and its changing frequently. Is it possible to set Auto-run of my app every hour automatically in shinyapps.io? If so how is it possible.

Q2: How to publish my shiny dashboard in AWS, including Auto Trigger too.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: for Q2, just study shiny-server in Linux

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to explain given the lack of reproducible example.

Use `reactivePoll` instead of `reactive`

```
data <- reactivePoll(
  intervalMillis = 1000 * 60 * 60, 
  session, 
  checkFunc = function(){
    Sys.time()
  }, 
  valueFunc = function(){
    # call API and return data here
  }
)
```

The above will run `checkFunc` at every `intervalMillis`, if the results of `checkFunc` is different then `valueFunc` is returned.

This will work wherever you deploy, see [Shiny Server Community](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/) edition to deploy your own server. You can see examples on [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-shiny-server-on-ubuntu-16-04).